# Moving 3d shapes with keyboard in OpenGL with C++

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut, opengl-compat

I'm trying to move the pyramid and cubic "separately" to front-back , up-down and right-left using arrows and page-up, page-down keys but I couldn't make it yet  , none of the tow shape are moving my 2 questions are  : how can i chose witch one of these shapes i want to move  , and why none of them are moving ?
Thanks.

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
float xmove = 0, ymove = 0, zmove = 0;
float degree = 0;
float xscale = 1, yscale = 1, zscale = 1;
void right(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();//koordinat sistemimizetkilenmesin
    xmove += 0.1;
}
void left(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    xmove -= 0.1;
}
void up(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    ymove += 0.1;
}
void down(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    ymove -= 0.1;
}
void front(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    zmove -= 0.1;
}
void back(void)
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    zmove += 0.1;
}
void keyboard(int button, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button)
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:left(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:right(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:up(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:down(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:front(); break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:back(); break;
    glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
void Settings()
{
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT , GL_NICEST);
}
void polygons(void)
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(xscale, yscale, zscale);
    glTranslatef(1.5, 0.0, -8.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);//pyramid
    // fronat face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // down face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //back
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //left 
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //reed
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.0, -8.0); 
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //cubic
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //pink
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //down face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f); //orange
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //front face
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    //back
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //yellow
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    //left
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    //right
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();
}
void DrawingFunction()//painting
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    polygons();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void AppearanceAdjustment(int x, int y)
{
    int aspect = x / y;
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45,aspect,0.1,20);

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("3d shapes");
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawingFunction);
    glutReshapeFunc(AppearanceAdjustment);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
    Settings();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glLoadIdentity()` has to be called in `DrawingFunction`:

```cpp
void DrawingFunction()//painting
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity(); // <----
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    polygons();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Add an array of offsets and an object number:

```cpp
int object = 0;
float xmove[]{ 0, 0 };
float ymove[]{ 0, 0 };
float zmove[]{ 0, 0 };
```

Add object selection buttons and change the offset of the selected object.
`glutPostRedisplay()` has to be executed after the switch statement:

```cpp
void keyboard(int button, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button)
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_F1: object = 0; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F2: object = 1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: xmove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: xmove[object] += 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  ymove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP: ymove[object] += 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP: zmove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN: zmove[object] += 0.1; break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

You have to translate the objects object by `glTranslatef(xmove[i], ymove[i], zmove[i])`. I recommend to use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml):

```cpp
void polygons(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(xscale, yscale, zscale);
    glTranslatef(1.5, 0.0, -8.0);

    glTranslatef(xmove[0], ymove[0], zmove[0]); // <--- translate pyramid

    // draw pyramid
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);//pyramid
    // [...]
    glEnd();

    glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.0, -8.0); 
    glTranslatef(xmove[1], ymove[1], zmove[1]); // <--- translate cube

    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //cubic
    // [...]
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}
```

---

Example code:

```cpp
int object = 0;
float xmove[]{ 0, 0 };
float ymove[]{ 0, 0 };
float zmove[]{ 0, 0 };

float degree = 0;
float xscale = 1, yscale = 1, zscale = 1;

void keyboard(int button, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button)
    {
        case GLUT_KEY_F1: object = 0; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_F2: object = 1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_LEFT: xmove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT: xmove[object] += 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  ymove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_UP: ymove[object] += 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP: zmove[object] -= 0.1; break;
        case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN: zmove[object] += 0.1; break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void Settings()
{
    glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT , GL_NICEST);
}

void polygons(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(degree, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(xscale, yscale, zscale);
    glTranslatef(1.5, 0.0, -8.0);

    glTranslatef(xmove[0], ymove[0], zmove[0]); // <--- translate pyramid

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);//pyramid
    // fronat face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // down face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //back
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //left 
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //reed
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();


    glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.0, -8.0); 
    glTranslatef(xmove[1], ymove[1], zmove[1]); // <--- translate cube


    glBegin(GL_QUADS); //cubic
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //pink
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    //down face
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f); //orange
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    //front face
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //blue
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    //back
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //yellow
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    //left
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); //red
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    //right
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); //green
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
}

void DrawingFunction()//painting
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    polygons();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void AppearanceAdjustment(int x, int y)
{
    int aspect = x / y;
    glViewport(0, 0, x, y);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45,aspect,0.1,20);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE); 
    glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("3d shapes");
    glutDisplayFunc(DrawingFunction);
    glutReshapeFunc(AppearanceAdjustment);
    glutSpecialFunc(keyboard);
    Settings();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad , Thank you so much sir

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a key press to pick one of the shapes similar to how you trigger the up, down, left, right ... Etc functions. Say press a for the first shape then set a global int ishape= 1 or ishape=2 if b is pressed. The draw function will then check the value of ishape to see which shape it should move. But really you need a vector of move for each shape else their displacements will be mixed up.Then you need to apply gltranslate on the shape that needs to be displaced using the move vector.